# SpriteKit Shader Glitch(SKAttributeValue crash)

Tags: ios, swift, opengl-es, sprite-kit, shader

I am using a simple shader, here it is

```
void main() {
    vec2 p = -1.0 + 2.0 * v_tex_coord;
    float len = length(p);
    vec2 uv = v_tex_coord - (p/len)*(sin(len*22.-u_time*5.28) + 1.)*0.1;
    gl_FragColor = texture2D(u_texture, uv) * u_color;
}
```

This is how I set it up to use it for nodes with different colors

```
self.swirlShader.attributes = [SKAttribute(name: "u_color", type: SKAttributeType.vectorFloat4)]
```

From time to time it glitches and adding nodes to the scene affects how it works, basically it changes the texture of the node to the sine function. 
[glitch example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7Ya9k.png)

This alternates between all nodes really fast, only when some particle is emitting, like the bottom-left one.
When 2 nodes collide they explode and when that happens it also crashes and the last instruction in the stack trace is [SKAttributeValue copyValueTo: type: count:]

Also getting this from time to time

```
Execution of the command buffer was aborted due to an error during execution. Caused GPU Hang Error (IOAF code 3)
```

EDIT: I found out that using a new instance of the shader for each node and increasing the number of nodes drastically increases the occurrence of the crash, but not the glitch, it actually changed it and made it less frequent. Here is the glitch with new instance for every node: [glitch with new shader instances](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BkF72.png)

UPDATE: It appears to be some kind of threading issue related to the access of the shader or the execution of the shader. Also, why is the CPU time going up and down when using a shader and steady low when not? I thought shaders work directly on the GPU.

UPDATE 2: Found out that it was crashing because I was adding too many nodes to the scene(around 3600). I don't know why though, because it isn't consistent and only happens when using a shader.
The glitch is still present and I can't figure out what exactly is causing it. I think it is again from adding nodes to the scene, but it is not consistent enough to run a lot of tests. 
I tried removing all actions and doing manual alpha, rotation etc. updates, but that wasn't the cause. In one of the tests everything froze and started jumping back and forth between 2-3 frames, as well as jumping forward a few times, something is causing a GPU hang error.
I am not sure how the shader is being affected by anything outside it's variables, but it's messing with the GPU.

Comment: Looks like a good place to [file a bug](https://bugreport.apple.com).

Comment: Thanks for the updates. Can I target some questions to you about shaders in SpriteKit, in a general sense... some questions that will be very naive and possibly super stupid?

Comment: @Confused Go ahead and ask, but I am pretty sure if they are naive and stupid they have already been answered somewhere.

Comment: @NikolaBozhkov I'd be very interested to hear if you solved the crash.  I've added the use of two very simple shaders that are used in perhaps 3 places at any one time, and get this same crash intermittently.  Commenting out the shader removes the crash entirely.

Comment: @PKCLsoft No, I don't remember fixing it. I would suggest going for metal shaders, it's a bit of boilerplate but you can be sure that you won't have any issues. Although, I did use GLSL shaders in a Metal project I did 1 year ago and I had no issues. Another thing to try is to build for TestFlight and check if the crash can be reproduced, could be a debug build issue (I don't remember trying this). Sorry I couldn't give you any useful info : /